# Pango-WARNING **: failed to choose a font, expect ugly output

Tags: fonts, gtk, cairo, pango

I'm getting this error when starting anything that uses the Pango library.  I'm using Kubuntu 9.10.  I've done 'sudo apt-get --reinstall install' on libgtk* libcairo* libpango* and fontconfig, with no luck.

Could someone point me in the right direction?  Thanks.

Answer (score 31):

I did a lot of searching on this and never found a decent answer. My issue involved running virt-manager (an xwindows based utility) on a remote server. I have all the fonts on my xwindows box but not on the remote host.

the i ran 'yum install xorg-x11-font*' on the remote host everything worked fine.

Comment: Thanks - I was setting up a minimal machine without a full desktop, but with a couple of X-apps. This was exactly what I needed.

Comment: Thanks!     On CentOS I had to install:xorg-x11-fonts-Type1. Also installed xorg-x11-fonts-100dpi and xorg-x11-fonts-75dpi -- not sure which I needed, if either.

Answer (score 12):

I ran into this on Amazon Linux, with the minimal set of X packages necessary to run vncserver, and had to install `dejavu-sans-fonts` and `dejavu-serif-fonts`.

Comment: This fixed it for me on RHEL/CentOS 6. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Verify font file permissions, especially on fonts you have installed manually, such as: out of package management scope.

Pango may fail with this error when the font is not readable by the desktop user. Example: font installed under /usr/share/fonts/..., owned by root, no others have read rights.

Answer (score 0):

Your fonts are probably installed in /usr/X11R6/share/fonts but since pango-1.24 the fonts should be in /usr/share/fonts. The solution is to link the X11 fonts:

> `ln -s /usr/X11R6/share/fonts /usr/share`

This should fix the problem.

Comment: I don't have a permission to do that. How do I tell `pango` to look for the fonts in `~/tmp/share/fonts`?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that font you are using with pango is installed on the machine.

Check for installed fonts in /usr/share/fonts directory.

To install new fonts try the steps mentioned in [this](http://vietunicode.sourceforge.net/howto/fontlinux.html) document: