# How to avoid/fix/stop Eclipse from getting this SIGSEGV?

Tags: eclipse, segmentation-fault

I'm using Eclipse Helios and I get this:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0xb13aa83b, pid=5456, tid=3076675264
#
# JRE version: 6.0_22-b04
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (17.1-b03 mixed mode, sharing linux-x86 )
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libxul.so+0xce183b]
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /home/wena/hs_err_pid5456.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
#
Aborted
```

**UPDATE**: I haven't had this crash in a long while and I don't remember when it stopped occurring or what caused it to stop.

Comment: Well the first thing to try is Java 1.6.0_23

Comment: @ska Am getting the same crash with 6.0_23-b05.

Comment: I got this when running MAT (Eclipse Memory Analyser Tool), but also got Pango warnings. Turned out installing X fonts helped, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2568408/pango-warning-failed-to-choose-a-font-expect-ugly-output

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using the CDT, try appending these two lines to eclipse.ini:

```
-XX:CompileCommand=exclude,org/eclipse/cdt/internal/core/dom/parser/cpp/CPPASTFunctionDeclarator,postAccept
-XX:CompileCommand=exclude,org/eclipse/cdt/internal/core/dom/parser/cpp/semantics/CPPSemantics,declaredBefore
```

Answer (score 0):

`libxul` is part of the Mozilla browser engine. It's used, among other things, in the JavaDoc popup and view.

Check your installation of `xulrunner` and upgrade/fix it. You may also want to check the value of the environment variable `MOZILLA_FIVE_HOME`: Does it exist? Does it point to the correct version of xulrunner?