# Git mergetool meld on windows using putty

Tags: git, merge, commit, putty, meld

I have used meld to merge the conflicted files in git for a long time while running on Ubuntu. Now I need to merge files, but my environnement has changed. I now use a PC on Windows 7, and connects to a CentOS server using Putty. I installed meld on the server :

> Package meld-1.3.1-2.el6.noarch already installed and latest version

I tried even to install meld for windows on my PC... it doesn't help. When running :

> > git mergetool -t meld

Here's the response :

```
Merging the files: gagglon/v4/www/includes/php/test.php
Normal merge conflict for 'gagglon/v4/www/includes/php/test.php':
{local}: modified
{remote}: modified
Hit return to start merge resolution tool (meld):
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/bin/meld", line 61, in <module>
import gtk
File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/gtk-2.0/gtk/__init__.py", line 64, in <module>
_init()
File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/gtk-2.0/gtk/__init__.py", line 52, in _init
_gtk.init_check()
RuntimeError: could not open display
gagglon/v4/www/includes/php/test.php seems unchanged.
Was the merge successful? [y/n] n
merge of gagglon/v4/www/includes/php/test.php failed
```

What can I do to get meld back, or could you help me find another tool I could use that would be also easy to use like meld ? Any easy interface would do...

Thanks ahead !

Comment: Is it a `DISPLAY` environment variable issue, as in https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=591502?

Comment: I didn't even knew what were environnment variable ^^ Yet a printenv command doesn't show any DISPLAY variable, even after fresh launching of a terminal...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On CentOS, [most](http://www.centos.org/modules/newbb/viewtopic.php?topic_id=33396&forum=55) of [the threads](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=591502) I found insist on the importance of setting properly the environment variable `$DISPLAY`.

> Noticed that there DISPLAY environment variable was gone in that terminal session.
>   Opening new terminal session or use different terminal session solves the problem...

```
export DISPLAY=":1.0"
```

But on putty, is is harder, as explained in [this thread](http://www.centos.org/modules/newbb/viewtopic.php?topic_id=38151&forum=55):

> All the system-config commands are designed to be ran via X11 (a Linux GUI).
>   From the error messages its trying to run `gtk` commands which means its trying to open a GUI window, which is not going to happen via putty.
>   I would look for other commands to setup what your trying to do.

Why wouldn't you use [meld on Windows directly](https://code.google.com/p/meld-installer/)?

With putty only, you can try [this solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/76118), based on X11 forwarding:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vpiko.jpg]

That means:

- installing an X11 server on Windows, like [**XMing**](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xming/),
- don't forget the fonts:  `yum install xorg-x11-font*`.

Comment: Very interesting, thank you, I read the same thread earlier but didn't understand all of this... I have installed Meld on Windows, but the git is installed on the server and using git mergetool on the server won't trigger a software running on the local machine, I guess... I could be wrong, but if so I didn't find how to. This said, I'm a little confuse, what help would bring to set the display variable by following the X11 forwarding solution ?

Comment: @JeremyBelolo it would declare the Windows display for the X11 of your Centos to use.

Comment: Hi, thanks again... But still doesn't work. DISPLAY=localhost:10.0 appears on printenv, but still getting RuntimeError: could not open display.

Comment: @JeremyBelolo maybe "localhost" isn't properly interpreted. Try that tutorial to see if it works better: http://www.math.umn.edu/systems_guide/putty_xwin32.html

Comment: @JeremyBelolo and you might be missing an X11 server running on your Windows, like XMing, as mentioned in http://courses.cms.caltech.edu/cs11/misc/xwindows.html.

Comment: LOL that's something like fabulous ^^ That kinda worked, but kinda... Well, look : http://i.imgur.com/bkXS7Xw.png ... I was like "hurray" when it opened and then "oooohhhh" :)

Comment: /usr/share/meld/meldapp.py:502: PangoWarning: failed to choose a font, expect ugly output. engine-type='PangoRenderFc', script='latin'
  self.widget.show()
/usr/share/meld/meldapp.py:502: PangoWarning: failed to choose a font, expect ugly output. engine-type='PangoRenderFc', script='common'
  self.widget.show()

Comment: np, lets just continue here :) Have yo ugot an idea of what I should do to get this font issue fixed ?

Comment: @JeremyBelolo do you have installed an X11 server on your Windows?

Comment: @JeremyBelolo that X11 server should include fonts (mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/a/5812485/6309)

Comment: I was looking at the exact same thread. I'm going to give it a try

Comment: yum install xorg-x11-font* did it ! success :) Thank you very much for your help, you rocks !

Comment: @JeremyBelolo great! I have added the two steps (X11 server and fonts) in the answer for more visibility.