# Git : mergetool meld on windows using putty - errors

Tags: git, centos, x11, putty, meld

I have [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19346446/git-mergetool-meld-on-windows-using-putty) as a reference about how to use meld with putty, using X11 forwarding. I tried to reproduce it on my new Centos 7 server. I got many errors which I fixed by looking on Google and installing dependencies `yum install dconf dconf-editor` , `yum install pygobject3 pycairo` and then applying `export NO_AT_BRIDGE=1` to remove the last error that popped up :

```
** (meld:9885): WARNING **: Couldn't connect to accessibility bus: Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-VTd0T4zB93: Connection refused
```

So, now there are no errors displayed, when I type `git mergetool -t meld` it does open meld on my windows 7 computer (after something like 15s !!!), but the windows are empty. I don't see the diff. More than that, if I try to click on the `file` tab for example, it doesn't move at all. Same for every button.

Can someone help ? Thanks ahead.

Comment: Not exactly an answer but have you tried a different, console based mergetool? X11 over SSH is very very slow.

Comment: Well the only one I tried is vimdiff and it's REALLY confusing when you're not familiar with vim - which I'm not, and even less my coworkers for who I will have to describe a full workflow :/

Comment: Then why work via SSH at all? Don't you have the codebase checked out on your local machines?

Comment: I do, but I also have to sync between the prod server and the dev server, on which all devs are pushing their work. And sometimes, there is a conflict between the dev server and something that has been done on the rush directly in prod...

Answer (score 0):

With the updated question from your comments:

Having a `dev` server push directly to `production` is a bad idea for exactly the reason you're naming. Here is an alternative:

Instead of `dev` pushing to `production` it will push back to your Git central repository in its own branch, lets call it `dev-pushback`. In order for it to go to `production` one of your devs must review the changes and merge them into `master`. Your deployment system will then pick up `master` and push it to `production`.

Comment: That's a change of workflow I'm not able to do, sadly ! I didn't design the architecture, just trying to enhance a little the way we work here by getting Git in, getting everyone a private repository that pushes to dev, instead of asking their colleagues if files are free to be edited... And getting developments to prod better than copying the files over FTP :) Well, in short, I can't push my changes more on the matter, I think.

Comment: Then Git doesn't fit, sorry. In my opinion asking devs to connect to a host via X11 and play with a GUI just for a merge is no viable workflow.